# Is there any event in ionic 3 when alert box is presented to the user

Tags: javascript, angular, events, ionic-framework

I have a requirement to display the image(help icon) in the ionic alert popup. I am using localization in our application. So what I have done right now is displayed the image using CSS class from translate strings as follows,

```
"PBMNotConnected": "<div>We didn't detect a PBM connected to your device.</div><p class='pbmAlertInfoBox'>Please select the <span class='infoIcon' (click)='goToHelp()'></span> (info icon) for help.</p>",
```

Now I am able to see the help icon in the alert box but, I want to bind the click event to that help icon. I have added `(click)` attribute in translate string but it doesn't work.

Following is the common code for presenting alert popup

```
/**
 * show alert message
 * @description pass non translated strings of title, subtitle, message and buttons text
 */
presentAlert(title, subtitle, message, cssClass, okText, hideButtons?:boolean) {
    let buttons = [];
    if(!hideButtons){
        buttons = [this.getTranslate(okText, {})];
    }
    let alert = this.alertController.create({
        title: this.getTranslate(title, {}),
        subTitle: subtitle ? this.getTranslate(subtitle, {}) : '',
        message: this.getTranslate(message, {}),
        cssClass: cssClass,
        buttons: buttons,
        enableBackdropDismiss: false
    });
    alert.present();
    return alert;
}
```

and then I have tried to bind the event using following code manually,

```
let alert = this.popUpService.presentAlert('error', undefined, 'PBMNotConnected', 'custom-popup-ok error', 'ok');
let elements: any = document.getElementsByClassName('.pbmAlertInfoBox .infoIcon');
  if(elements.length > 0){
     elements[0].click = () => {
       this.goToHelp();
     }
  }
```

but now, the problem is I don't know when exactly the alert popup opens, so I need your help to know any event available after opening the alert popup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that there is a requirement to show customized alerts, but if feels odd to try to solve it the way you do. What was blocking you to just use combination of "buttons" and message properties to achieve what you want?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting to use simple modal instead alert? or make changes with the design itself?

Comment: what I think I am trying to say is that alertController is pretty customizable:  with buttons, css, message using html template etc. So there should be no problem for you to use all that for your goal. But based on your code you are trying to get actual customizations while you already are calling that alertController. Maybe its better to have a pre-step method that does create all customizations ready and then just instantiates the alertController with those options for you? basically you need "getCustomization(conditions).then((customizations)=>{this.presentAlert(customizations)})

Comment: Oh Ok... can you point me to any demo example so that I can refer it?